# Pandas read_table skips rows with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in a tsv file using pandas read_table, but for some reason, the first line is being removed from the file.

test.pln (File is [here](https://gist.github.com/kyranstar/e1894251b40e3bfd4f3cad0293d9e011)):

```
Class index 0   0   0   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3
fall    spring  summer  fall    spring  summer  fall    spring  summer  fall    spring  summer
0                                               
1                                               
2                                               
3                                               
4                                               
5   COMP 140                                            
6       COMP 182                                        
7   MATH 331
```

Then, running the command:

```
pd.read_table("test.pln", header=[0,1],index_col=0)
```

I get this result:

```
Class index         0                     1                  2                \
             fall    spring summer fall spring summer fall spring summer
0
1                 NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
2                 NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
3                 NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
4                 NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
5            COMP 140       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
6                 NaN  COMP 182    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
7            MATH 331       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN

Class index    3
            fall spring summer
0
1            NaN    NaN    NaN
2            NaN    NaN    NaN
3            NaN    NaN    NaN
4            NaN    NaN    NaN
5            NaN    NaN    NaN
6            NaN    NaN    NaN
7            NaN    NaN    NaN
```

As you can see, there is an empty row. When I try to access values from row 0, I get a KeyError. However, these values are present in the file, so the row should be full of NaNs. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post desired input and output as text, not as an image.

Comment: try 'pd.read_csv("test.pln",header=[0,1], sep='\s\s+')

Comment: @ScottBoston This crashes while extracting the multi index columns. Line 0 and Line 1 are identical anyway, so I'm not sure why that would be the problem

Comment: Hrm.. Can you share the file?

Comment: @ScottBoston https://gist.github.com/kyranstar/e1894251b40e3bfd4f3cad0293d9e011

Comment: Interesting your header data isn't \n, so it thinks that zero is part of summer.  Can you modify your source to put a \n after the header?

Comment: The trick I used without getting too fancy was I opened 'test.pln' in MS Word choose to show all invisible characters.

Comment: For me, theres a /r/n after the header. Adding an additional one doesn't help either.

Comment: Try this, without the index_col parameter. `pd.read_csv('Desktop/test.pln',sep='\t',header=[0,1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this without index_col, the we drop that first index column using a tuple in `drop`:

```
pd.read_csv('Desktop/test.pln',sep='\t',header=[0,1]).drop(('Class index','Unnamed: 0_level_1'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          0                     1                  2                  3              
       fall    spring summer fall spring summer fall spring summer fall spring summer
0       NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
1       NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
2       NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
3       NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
4       NaN       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
5  COMP 140       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
6       NaN  COMP 182    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
7  MATH 331       NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
```